# Redux Form onsubmit make API call

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, redux-form

I have used redux form to structure a multiple page form. When I submit the form, as of now, it just console logs the data. But I would like it to make an API post request using the form data.

So far I have tried editing the already made "showResults" page which called when the final form page is submitted. I get errors such as the folowing `Uncaught (in promise) API not configured`

Here is the showResults.js file which I have renamed an edited.

```
import { API } from "aws-amplify";

export default (async function submitSite(values) {
  return API.post("sites", "/sites", {
    body: values
  }) 
});
console.log("submitted");
```

As you can see I have a console log at the end to signify that the code worked, but the console log happens as soon as I run to the code, it doesnt wait until I submit.

Comment: Where have you configured the API? Also, that console log should be inside the async function.

Comment: @Colin What do you mean where is it configured ? and when I out the console log in the function it greys out the code

Comment: Read the AWS amplify docs, you need to configure your API before you can use it. I'm not sure what you mean regarding grays out the code, that seems like an editor issue rather than a programming issue per se.

Comment: @Colin For the life of me I don't know how to configure the API, I have used `serverless deploy` and tested the API and its working. But when called from the forms submit, Im having the same issue

Comment: It's in the readme: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js#configuration

Comment: @Colin So in what file do I write `import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import aws_exports from './aws-exports';

Amplify.configure(aws_exports);

// or you don't want to install all the categories
import Amplify from '@aws-amplify/core';
import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth';
import aws_exports from './aws-exports';

// in this way you are only importing Auth and configuring it.
Amplify.configure(aws_exports);` 

and where do reference my post api

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that the `console.log` is not inside the body of the function. Therefore, the log is called, indeed, as soon as you run the code.

To log only when you submit :

```
import { API } from "aws-amplify";

export default (async function submitSite(values) {
  console.log("submitted");
  return API.post("sites", "/sites", {
    body: values
  }) 
});
```